# 404 Bad Request Error while retrieving specific details using Swagger, But working in Postman

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have incorporated Swagger in my application. I am trying to get a individual details through id by hitting the endpoint in swagger. But I am getting the following error

**Controller**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/{clientId}/")

   public ResponseEntity<ClientDto> getClientById(@ApiParam(name = "Client Id", required = true) @PathVariable("clientId") UUID clientId){}
```

**Error**

```
 Error Code 400
 connection: close 
 content-length: 0 
 date: Tue, 22 May 2018 12:56:40 GMT
```

It's working correctly in Postman but I don't know why I am facing this error in swagger. Can somebody help me out from this?

Comment: 400 is Bad Request. Are you sure you are hitting the correct URL? What does the raw request look like (e.g. as seen on the Network tab in the browser's dev tools)? The more details you provide the more likely you are to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the reason for the issue.
The URL that I am trying to hit is

```
     @RequestMapping(value = "/{clientId}/")

   public ResponseEntity<ClientDto> getClientById(@ApiParam(name = "Client Id", required = true) @PathVariable("clientId") UUID clientId){}
```

I thought the **name** parameter in the **@ApiParam** is just used for display purpose in the swagger-UI but now I realized that it should match with **value** parameter in the **@RequestMapping**

I have changed the code from

```
 @ApiParam(name="Client Id") to  @ApiParam(name="clientId")
```